# Translate md5 hash generator in python into R

Tags: python, r, api, hash, md5

I am trying to use private APIs of Cryptopia. In order to use private API, Base64 encoded MD5 hash of the post parameters is needed. I found a python code from https://github.com/thebotguys/cryptopia-api-python/blob/master/cryptopia_api.py

While translating the code into R, the md5 hash generator got me in trouble. The hash results from python and R are different. Please fill me in how to fix.

Python:

```
post_parameters = {'Currency': 'BTC'}
post_data = json.dumps(post_parameters)
md5 = hashlib.md5()
jsonparams = post_data.encode('utf-8')
md5.update(jsonparams)
rcb64 = base64.b64encode(md5.digest()).decode('utf-8')
```

R:

```
post_parameters <- list("Currency" = "BTC")
post_data <- jsonlite::toJSON(post_parameters, auto_unbox=T)
jsonparams <- stri_enc_toutf8(post_data, is_unknown_8bit = FALSE, validate = FALSE)
rcb64 <- base64encode(digest(jsonparams, algo="md5", raw=T)
```

Instead of the last row, I tried this, but it also made another result.

`rcb64 <- base64encode(charToRaw(digest(jsonparams, algo="md5")))`

Comment: What package are you using for the R `base64encode` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one catch is that `toJSON` and `json.dumps` have different opinions on wether or not there should be a space after the colon in a JSON file. I see that

```
# pyhton
jsonparams
# '{"Currency": "BTC"} 
# R
cat(jsonparams)
# {"Currency":"BTC"}
```

So since the strings are different, they will not have the exact same MD5 hash. But unless the API has very strict whitespace rules, this shouldn't be too much of a problem.

The other thing is that if you want to match up with hashes of just the strings, you should use `serialize=FALSE` with the `digest()` function in R.

```
rcb64 <- digest::digest(jsonparams, algo="md5", serialize = FALSE, raw=TRUE)
```

Assuming you start out with the same input string, this will return the same result between R and Pyhton. For example

```
# R
RCurl::base64Encode(digest::digest("hello", algo="md5", serialize = FALSE, raw=TRUE))
# [1] "XUFAKrxLKna5cZ2REBfFkg=="
```

and

```
# python
md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update("hello")
base64.b64encode(md5.digest())
# 'XUFAKrxLKna5cZ2REBfFkg=='
```

Since you seem to only have ASCII values in your string, the fact that you need UTF-8 encoding really isn't going to make any difference at all in the result.